# How to load pem from gateway with Fabric

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys, fabric

I need to create a connection with Fabric 2 using 2 gateways.

```
c = Connection("user@IP", connect_kwargs={"key_filename": "xxxxx.pem"}, gateway=Connection("user@IP", connect_kwargs={"key_filename": "/home/xxxx/key.pem", gateway=Connection("user@IP", connect_kwargs={"password": "xxxxxxx"})))
```

The first gateway using the password connects just fine, but the second gateway instead of loading the key.pem file from the gateway host it loads it from my local environment, getting the following

```
File "/Users/xxxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 321, in _read_private_key_file
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/xxxxx/key.pem'
```

The key.pem key also requires a passphrase to be entered which can be passed as a connect_kwargs parameter in Fabric Connection instance.

I have also the issue that in the first gateway connection I cannot create a ~/.ssh/config file due to administration issues.

Is there a way to force paramiko do load the key from the gateway host rather than my local machine?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind was simpler than I thought...I just downloaded the pem keys on my local environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).